# Adding Custom Javascript to Skeleton Child Theme

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, child-theme

I'm trying to register & enqueue [ImageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/) in my Skeleton Child Theme on the main.php page to make an image map with hovering image effects. I added this code to the "Header Functions" section of my child theme's functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_js' );
function load_custom_js() {
    wp_register_script( 'jquery.imagemapster.js', 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascripts/jquery.imagemapster.js', 
    array('jquery'), '1.2.6', false );

    if ( is_page('Main') ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.imagemapster.js', 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascripts/jquery.imagemapster.js', 
    array('jquery'), '1.2.6', false );
    }
}
```

Now my site has ceased to work. The javascript file is located in the parent theme directory, so is it correct to use get_template_directory_uri instead of get_stylesheet_directory_uri? Does each theme have a particular place where one should add custom functions or am I correct in adding it under "Header Functions"? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One problem: if you define the script in a `wp_register_script()` like so:

```
wp_register_script( 
    'jquery.imagemapster.js', 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascripts/jquery.imagemapster.js', 
    array('jquery'), 
    '1.2.6', 
    false 
);
```

...then you only need to reference the *defined script's name* in the `wp_enqueue_script()` call, like so:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.imagemapster.js' );
```

Re-declaring all of the parameters in `wp_enqueue_script()` *shouldn't* cause the fatal error you describe; however, it could cause unintended consequences (especially if the declarations do not match between `wp_register_script()` and `wp_enqueue_script()`).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [`get_template_directory()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory)?  This should actually return the parent theme's directory when **called** from your child theme's functions.php.

Out of curiosity, does the path of your child theme's directory get returned when you're calling `get_template_directory_uri` right now from your child theme?

Comment: I figured it out - I had accidentally deleted a critical ?> tag from a different function. Everything works fine now.